# PowerShell custom provider RemoveItem

Tags: powershell, powershell-provider

I'm implementing a custom [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) provider. I'm now working on the remove-item cmdlet implementation.

The RemoveItem method has the following signature:

```
protected override void RemoveItem(string path, bool recurse)
```

When I type: `Remove-Item .\Myobject -recurse` the PowerShell infrastructure provides me with the value `true` in the `recurse` parameter of the RemoveItem method.

However when I type: Remove-Item .\MyObject' I get a question:

> The item at MyObject has children and the Recurse parameter was not specified. If you continue,
>    all children will be removed with the item. Are you sure you want to continue?
>   [Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):

I guess this question is presented to my by the PowerShell infrastructure. This is perfectly fine because the object that I want to remove is a container. If I answer yes to the above question the PowerShell infrastructure does not set the recurse parameter. In fact it is false when my `RemoveItem` method is called. I would except the parameter to be true because I answered yes to the question.

My questions are:

1. Why does PowerShell not set the bool recurse parameter to the correct value?
2. Do I need to get the value (answer to the question) in some other way? How?
3. If above is not possible is there a way to suppress the question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to quietly remove a directory with content in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909167/how-to-quietly-remove-a-directory-with-content-in-powershell)

Answer (score 5):

Ultimately if you're asked to remove a container then it is inherently recursive unless the container doesn't contain other containers.  I believe PowerShell prompts because the action affects more than the user might initially be aware of (all the container's contents) and warrants confirmation.  So in this case, I think the -recurse is used to tell PowerShell "I know what I'm doing".

Where -recurse makes more sense is if you were to execute something like this:

```
Remove-Item *.bak -recurse
```

In this case, you want to recursively search for files to delete.  Unfortunately the Recurse parameter on Remove-Item is broken for this usage - from the docs:

> Because the Recurse parameter in this
>   cmdlet is faulty, the command uses 
>   the Get-Childitem cmdlet to get the
>   desired files, and it uses the 
>   pipeline operator to pass them to the
>   Remove-Item cmdlet.

So the way to do this currently is:

```
Get-ChildItem . -r *.bak | Remove-Item
```

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress the question by setting `$ConfirmPreference="None"`

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/12/15/confirmpreference.aspx