# How to recursively delete an entire directory with PowerShell 2.0?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-7, filesystems, delete-directory

What is the simplest way to forcefully delete a directory and all its subdirectories in PowerShell? I am using PowerShell V2 in Windows 7.

I have learned from several sources that the most obvious command, `Remove-Item $targetDir -Recurse -Force`, does not work correctly. This includes a statement in the PowerShell V2 online help (found using `Get-Help Remove-Item -Examples`) that states:

> ...Because the Recurse parameter in this cmdlet is faulty, the command uses the Get-Childitem cmdlet to get the desired files, and it uses the pipeline operator to pass them to the Remove-Item cmdlet...

I have seen various examples that use **Get-ChildItem** and pipe it to **Remove-Item**, but the examples usually remove some set of files based on a filter, not the entire directory.

I am looking for the cleanest way to blow out an entire directory, files and child directories, without generating any user warning messages using the least amount of code. A one-liner would be nice if it is easy to understand.

Comment: powershell, i know, but `RD /S /Q`

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667145/powershell-custom-provider-removeitem

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate. I reviewed 1667145 before posting. It is asking why PowerShell is not setting the Recurse bool parameter properly when calling the Remove-Item method implemention of a custom PowerShell provider. I was asking about Remove-Item behavior as it relates to the the built in file system provider.

Comment: "RD /S /Q" doesn't seem to work in PowerShell -- says "Remove-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '/q'."

Comment: `rd` is an alias for `Remove-Item` in powershell. `cmd /c "rd /s /q"` works, though.

Comment: I cant believe powershell breaks basic functionality like this by hiding perfectly functional msdos commands!  you can use rmdir or rd in cmd but they are both hijacked in powershell

Comment: There is also this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53561052/284111

Answer (score 798, accepted):

```
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force some_dir
```

does indeed work as advertised here.

```
rm -r -fo some_dir
```

are shorthand aliases that work too.

As far as I understood it, the `-Recurse` parameter just doesn't work correctly when you try deleting a filtered set of files recursively. For killing a single dir and everything below it seems to work fine.

Comment: I think you are correct.

I was getting a "Cannot remove the item at 'some directory' because it is in use." error and assumed it was an issue with the recursion algorithm and went searching for a workaround.

It turns out I had a process I fired off earlier in the script that was working in the target directory. When changed the script to wait for the other process the "Remove-Item -Recurse -Force" command works.

Always look in the mirror first:)

Comment: I've found that I need to run this twice when run on a directory that contains subdirectories. The first time, there will be a lot of "The directory is not empty" errors.  The second time, it completes with no errors.

Comment: Kristopher Johnson, I get similar errors with varying tools on Windows 7. It seems that the delete call returns earlier than a file or folder is actually removed, causing trouble sometimes. This seems to happen in Explorer, Far, cmd and PowerShell.

Comment: @KristopherJohnson I have seen the exact same behavior on several machines.  But unlike Joey it only happens with PowerShell, and no other application.  And it is very annoying, and would be a disaster for reliable scripts.

Comment: @Joey "It seems that the delete call returns earlier than a file or folder is actually removed, causing trouble sometimes." --> For clarification: the parent folder will not be deleted and one gets the following error: "[parent folder] cannot be removed because it is not empty." I see this happen constantly on (slow) networked drives. The only solution is the old one: `cmd /c rd` as stated below.

Comment: What's  about "The directory is not empty" errors ?http://serverfault.com/questions/199921/powershell-remove-force Maybe better get-childitem * -include *.csv -recurse | remove-item I don't know. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1668471/206730

Comment: I've had this error occuring while Explorer had the given folder or a subfolder open. Closing the window or navigating away would solve it.

Comment: @Andreas, usually explorer doesn't keep handles on directories on a way that other programs cannot delete them. Might be a rogue shell extension.

Comment: when I use the rm alias in a try block and an error is observed (eg, file in use), it does not catch the error even in general catch block.  switching to Remove-Item does land in the catch when the same arguments are applied.

Comment: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'rf'.

Comment: @LukeCarelsen: Yes. PowerShell has no concept of combining multiple switch parameters into a single argument like getopt allows. You always have to give each argument separately, although you can shorten them as long as they remain unambiguous. So for PowerShell you need `-r -fo`, the latter requiring two letters to distinguish from `-Filter`.

Comment: @Joey thanks for clearing that up. seems im missing  big chunk of the inner workings of the power shell.

Comment: does `fo` mean foreach or force?

Comment: @Alex: There is no `-Foreach` parameter for that cmdlet, so it is `-Force`. In fact, the `o` is necessary to distinguish it from `-Filter`.

Comment: With PowerShell 5.1 it can handle long paths as well. You have to prepend "\\?\" for normal paths, like "\\?\D:\SomeDirWithLongSubDirs" or "\\?\UNC\Server\Share\SomeDirWithLongSubDirs". And you have to use -LiteralPath.

Answer (score 46):

I used:

```
rm -r folderToDelete
```

This works for me like a charm (I stole it from Ubuntu).

Comment: Doesn't that require cygwin, git, or some other tool that can simulate a bash shell on Windows?

Comment: @Pete, no, it does not require anything but PowerShell. `rm` is an alias for `Remove-Item` in PowerShell's default configuration. Check the output of `Get-Alias rm` for more details. The `-r` is taking advantage of PowerShell's partial matching behavior on parameters. Since `Remove-Item` only has the one parameter that starts with an 'r', `-Recurse`, `-r` matches that. Thus, the following all will work the same: `rm -r`, `rm -re`, `Remove-Item -Recurse`. (Note that neither `rm -rf` nor `rm -r -f` will work, but `rm -r -fo` will. `-rf` matches no parameters and `-f` matches more than one.)

Comment: How about that.  The Powershell rm alias for "Remove-Item -Recurse -Force some_dir" works better than directly using remove-item.  I received the same errors "Cannot remove the item at 'some directory' .  I switch from remove-item to rm -r with no errors!?

Comment: Interesting. I do have cygwin tools on my box, and had tried `rm -rf folder` and of course it failed. I initially down voted the answer (because it said Ubuntu). Thanks to the comment by @chwarr, I tried it without the `f` and it picked up the alias rather than rm binary. I wish Tuan would update his source (not sure if Tuan knew it was an alias or really thought it was the unix rm ;-)

Comment: Perhaps it's because I use the `-R` instead of `-r` (though as far as I know PowerShell is like the rest of Windows not case-sensitive hence it should't make a difference) but I got an error that the folders I'm trying to delete are not empty.

Comment: It does not work on PowerShell 5.1, I had to use `rm -r -fo` (`rm -r -f` does not work either since the `-f` parameter is ambiguous as it can match both `-Force` and `-Filter`).

Answer (score 34):

When deleting files recursively using a simple `Remove-Item "folder" -Recurse` I sometimes see an intermittent error : `[folder] cannot be removed because it is not empty.`

This answer attempts to prevent that error by individually deleting the files.

```
function Get-Tree($Path,$Include='*') { 
    @(Get-Item $Path -Include $Include -Force) + 
        (Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse -Include $Include -Force) | 
        sort pspath -Descending -unique
} 

function Remove-Tree($Path,$Include='*') { 
    Get-Tree $Path $Include | Remove-Item -force -recurse
} 

Remove-Tree some_dir
```

An important detail is the sorting of all the items with `pspath -Descending` so that the leaves are deleted before the roots.  The sorting is done on the `pspath` parameter since that has more chance of working for providers other than the file system. The `-Include` parameter is just a convenience if you want to filter the items to delete.

It's split into two functions since I find it useful to see what I'm about to delete by running

```
Get-Tree some_dir | select fullname
```

Comment: While resolving an issue using PowerShell in TFS build scripts, this proved to be the correct answer.

Comment: This is the solution for me as well.  Have yourself some points my good man!

Comment: Worked for me. I couldn't get recursive deletion of contents of a folder, but your solution worked for me. thanks

Comment: This is a very robust solution

Comment: I'm not sure why the accepted answer has so many votes - I personally still get intermittent errors using ```remove-item -recurse``` in Powershell v5  so this solution is best for me.

Comment: Possibly a more robust solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53561052/79113

Answer (score 17):

```
rm -r ./folder -Force
```

...worked for me

Answer (score 15):

If you're committed to powershell, you can use this, as explained in the accepted answer:

```
rm -r -fo targetDir
```

But I've found it to be faster to use Windows Command Prompt

```
rmdir /s/q targetDir
```

In addition to being faster, another advantage to using the command prompt option is that it starts deleting files immediately (powershell does some enumeration first), so if something breaks while it's running, you've at least made some progress in deleting files.

Comment: `rmdir` has the added benefit of successfully deleting read-only files (like in a `.git` folder) -- In older powershell versions, `(get-item targetDir).Delete($true)` will fail to delete git repos.

Answer (score 14):

Try this example. If the directory does not exist, no error is raised. You may need PowerShell v3.0.

```
remove-item -path "c:\Test Temp\Test Folder" -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Answer (score 10):

Use the old-school DOS command:

```
rd /s <dir>
```

Comment: If this is part of a script, you'd have to use `/q` (Quiet mode, do not ask if ok to remove a directory tree with /S) too.

Answer (score 10):

To avoid the "The directory is not empty" errors of the accepted answer, simply use the good old DOS command as suggested before. The full PS syntax ready for copy-pasting is:

```
& cmd.exe /c rd /S /Q $folderToDelete
```

Comment: It still gives "The directory is not empty" error for folders!?

Comment: I wanted to delete an Android Studio project and this is workded after i closed the Android Studio!

Answer (score 9):

For some reason John Rees' answer sometimes did not work in my case. But it led me in the following direction.
First I try to delete the directory recursively with the buggy -recurse option. Afterwards I descend into every subdir that's left and delete all files.

```
function Remove-Tree($Path)
{ 
    Remove-Item $Path -force -Recurse -ErrorAction silentlycontinue

    if (Test-Path "$Path\" -ErrorAction silentlycontinue)
    {
        $folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path –Directory -Force
        ForEach ($folder in $folders)
        {
            Remove-Tree $folder.FullName
        }

        $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -File -Force

        ForEach ($file in $files)
        {
            Remove-Item $file.FullName -force
        }

        if (Test-Path "$Path\" -ErrorAction silentlycontinue)
        {
            Remove-Item $Path -force
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the error when running my functions?  I'd like to know so that I can improve them.

Comment: Sorry, don't remember the exact setting. :/
I think it was when multiple sub-directories where involved.
It happened that the call to "Remove-Item -force -recurse" did not delete all files and in that case the last Remove-Tree failed because the directory was not empty.

That's why I came up with the new solution to first try the buggy built-in version (-force) and then manually descending into each directory and deleting "manually" what's left.

This version is in use regularly and up till now it is working. The only cause it failed was when a program still holds a handle to a directory.

Answer (score 5):

```
del <dir> -Recurse -Force # I prefer this, short & sweet
```

OR

```
remove-item <dir> -Recurse -Force
```

If you have a huge directory then what I usually do is

```
while (dir | where name -match <dir>) {write-host deleting; sleep -s 3}
```

Run this on another powershell terminal and it will stop when it is done.

Comment: I admit your idea with the monitoring can be useful, but it is barely different from just printing a message once it is finished, and in case there was any problem stopping the Remove-Item, your loop will never end.

Comment: @RaúlSalinas-Monteagudo true but it is definitely for prod or unattended use case scenario. It has to be small enough for someone to just remember and type on the go and not to run a sophisticated .ps1 file to just a directory.

Answer (score 4):

Deleting an entire folder tree sometimes works and sometimes fails with "Directory not empty" errors.  Subsequently attempting to check if the folder still exists can result in "Access Denied" or "Unauthorized Access" errors.  I do not know why this happens, though some insight may be gained from [this StackOverflow posting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25435600/854680).

I have been able to get around these issues by specifying the order in which items within the folder are deleted, and by adding delays.  The following runs well for me:

```
# First remove any files in the folder tree
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $FolderToDelete -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { -not ($_.psiscontainer) } | Remove-Item –Force

# Then remove any sub-folders (deepest ones first).    The -Recurse switch may be needed despite the deepest items being deleted first.
ForEach ($Subfolder in Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $FolderToDelete -Recurse -Force | Select-Object FullName, @{Name="Depth";Expression={($_.FullName -split "\\").Count}} | Sort-Object -Property @{Expression="Depth";Descending=$true}) { Remove-Item -LiteralPath $Subfolder.FullName -Recurse -Force }

# Then remove the folder itself.  The -Recurse switch is sometimes needed despite the previous statements.
Remove-Item -LiteralPath $FolderToDelete -Recurse -Force

# Finally, give Windows some time to finish deleting the folder (try not to hurl)
Start-Sleep -Seconds 4
```

A Microsoft TechNet article [Using Calculated Properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) in PowerShell was helpful to me in getting a list of sub-folders sorted by depth.

Similar reliability issues with **RD /S /Q** can be solved by running **DEL /F /S /Q** prior to **RD /S /Q** and running the **RD** a second time if necessary - ideally with a pause in between (i.e. using **ping** as shown below).

```
DEL /F /S /Q "C:\Some\Folder\to\Delete\*.*" > nul
RD /S /Q "C:\Some\Folder\to\Delete" > nul
if exist "C:\Some\Folder\to\Delete"  ping -4 -n 4 127.0.0.1 > nul
if exist "C:\Some\Folder\to\Delete"  RD /S /Q "C:\Some\Folder\to\Delete" > nul
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53553729/cannot-remove-item-the-directory-is-not-empty/53561052#53561052), which David Faivre mentioned in his answer below, for an explanation of why directory deletion sometimes fails, and a more sophisticated remedy.

Answer (score 3):

I took another approach inspired by @john-rees above - especially when his approach started to fail for me at some point.  Basically recurse the subtree and sort files by their path-length - delete from longest to the shortest

```
Get-ChildItem $tfsLocalPath -Recurse |  #Find all children
    Select-Object FullName,@{Name='PathLength';Expression={($_.FullName.Length)}} |  #Calculate the length of their path
    Sort-Object PathLength -Descending | #sort by path length descending
    %{ Get-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName } | 
    Remove-Item -Force
```

Regarding the -LiteralPath magic, here's another gotchya that may be hitting you: https://superuser.com/q/212808

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be issues where `Remove-Item -Force -Recurse` can intermittently fail on Windows because the underlying filesystem is asynchronous. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53561052/79113) seems to address it. The user has also been actively involved with the Powershell team [on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8211).

Answer (score 3):

while rm -r yields good results, the following method is faster:

```
$fso = New-Object -ComObject scripting.filesystemobject
$fso.DeleteFolder("D:\folder_to_remove")
```

To test this you can easily create a folder with X files (I used: [Disk Tools](http://www.soft.tahionic.com/download-file-generator/index.html) to quickly generate the files).

And then run each of the variants using:

```
Measure-Command {rm D:\FOLDER_TO_DELETE -r}
Measure-Command {Remove-Item -Path D:\FOLDER_TO_DELETE -Recurse -Force}
Measure-Command {rd -r FOLDER_TO_DELETE }
$fso.DeleteFolder("D:\folder_to_remove")
Measure-Command {$fso.DeleteFolder("D:\FOLDER_TO_DELETE")}
```

the results on my test folder were:

```
Remove-Item - TotalMilliseconds : 1438.708
rm - TotalMilliseconds : 1268.8473
rd - TotalMilliseconds : 739.5385
FSO - TotalMilliseconds : 676.8091
```

The results vary but on my system the winner was the fileSystemObject. I recommend testing this on the target file system to see which method is the best for you.

Answer (score 3):

Add a custom function in your PowerShell `$profile`:

```
function rmrf([string]$Path) {
    try {
        Remove-Item -Recurse -ErrorAction:Stop $Path
    } catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException] {
        # Ignore
        $Error.Clear()
    }
}
```

This is the most accurate representation of `rm -rf` behavior.

Answer (score 2):

**Another useful trick:**

If you find a lot of files with same or similar name convention (like mac file with dot prefix name... that famous file pulltion), you can easily remove them with one single line from the powershell like this:

```
ls -r .* | rm
```

This line is going to remove all files with a dot in the begining of the name inside the current directory, and all files with same circumstances inside other folders inside this directory too. Be aware about it when using it. :D

Comment: Why not use `rm -rf .*` ? I don`t have powershell to test, but I think it will work.

Comment: Its easy; if you just remove the "| rm" from the command, you can view a whole panorama of what you are going to delete, after you were sure, you can complete the command.

Comment: Por cierto, para quitar los archivos que empiecen con punto, (como los de mac) pero que tengan propiedad de oculto, puedes usar: ls -r -h .* | rm

Answer (score 2):

To delete the complete contents including the folder structure use

```
get-childitem $dest -recurse | foreach ($_) {remove-item $_.fullname -recurse}
```

The `-recurse` added to `remove-item` ensures interactive prompts are disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Really simple:

```
remove-item -path <type in file or directory name>, press Enter
```

Comment: You should offer an example execution too.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@John Rees](https://stackoverflow.com/users/37572/john-rees)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11520550/3158594) with some improvements.

Initial files **tree . /f**

```
C:\USERS\MEGAM\ONEDRIVE\ESCRITORIO\PWSHCFX
│   X-Update-PowerShellCoreFxs.ps1
│   z
│   Z-Config.json
│   Z-CoreFxs.ps1
│
├───HappyBirthday Unicorn
│       collection-of-unicorns-and-hearts-with-rainbows.zip
│       hand-drawing-rainbow-design.zip
│       hand-drawn-unicorn-birthday-invitation-template (2).zip
│       hontana.zip
│       Unicorn - Original.pdf
│       Unicorn-free-printable-cake-toppers.png
│       Unicorn.pdf
│       Unicorn.png
│       Unicorn2.pdf
│       Unicorn3.pdf
│       Unicorn4.pdf
│       Unicorn5.pdf
│       UnicornMLP.pdf
│
├───x
└───y
```

**Code**

```
function Get-ItemTree() {
    param (
        [Parameter()]
        [System.String]
        $Path = ".",

        [Parameter()]
        [System.String]
        $Include = "*",

        [Parameter()]
        [switch]
        $IncludePath,

        [Parameter()]
        [switch]
        $Force

    )
    $result = @()
    if (!(Test-Path $Path)) {
        throw "Invalid path. The path `"$Path`" doesn't exist." #Test if path is valid.
    }
    if (Test-Path $Path -PathType Container)
    {
        $result += (Get-ChildItem "$Path" -Include "$Include" -Force:$Force -Recurse) # Add all items inside of a container, if path is a container.
    }
    if($IncludePath.IsPresent)
    {
        $result += @(Get-Item $Path -Force) # Add the $Path in the result.
    }
    $result = ,@($result | Sort-Object -Descending -Unique -Property "PSPath") # Sort elements by PSPath property, order in descending, remove duplicates with unique.
    return  $result
}

function Remove-ItemTree {
    param (
        [Parameter()]
        [System.String]
        $Path, 

        [Parameter()]
        [switch]
        $ForceDebug
    )
    (Get-ItemTree -Path $Path -Force -IncludePath) | ForEach-Object{
        Remove-Item "$($_.PSPath)" -Force
        if($PSBoundParameters.Debug.IsPresent)
        {
            Write-Debug -Message "Deleted: $($_.PSPath)" -Debug:$ForceDebug
        }
    }
}

Write-Host "███ Test 1"
$a = Get-ItemTree "./Z-Config.json" -Force -Include "*" -IncludePath:$true # Tree of a file path. 1 element the file (IncludePath parameter = $true)
$a | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PSPath | ConvertTo-Json
Write-Host

Write-Host "███ Test 2"
$b = Get-ItemTree "./Z-Config.json" -Force -Include "*" -IncludePath:$false # Tree of a file path. No Result (IncludePath parameter = $false)
$b | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PSPath | ConvertTo-Json
Write-Host

Write-Host "███ Test 3"
$c = Get-ItemTree "." -Force -Include "*" -IncludePath:$true # Tree of a container path. All elements of tree and the container included (IncludePath parameter = $true).
$c | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PSPath | ConvertTo-Json
Write-Host

Write-Host "███ Test 4"
$d = Get-ItemTree "." -Force -Include "*" -IncludePath:$false # All elements of tree, except the container (IncludePath parameter = $false).
$d | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PSPath | ConvertTo-Json
Write-Host

Remove-ItemTree -Path "./HappyBirthday Unicorn" -Debug -ForceDebug #Remove the contents of container and remove the container. -Debug Prints debug messages and -ForceDebug forces to prints messages if DebugPreference is SilentlyContinue.
Remove-ItemTree -Path "./x" -Debug -ForceDebug #Remove the contents of container and remove the container. -Debug Prints debug messages and -ForceDebug forces to prints messages if DebugPreference is SilentlyContinue.
Remove-ItemTree -Path "./y" -Debug -ForceDebug #Remove the contents of container and remove the container. -Debug Prints debug messages and -ForceDebug forces to prints messages if DebugPreference is SilentlyContinue.
Remove-ItemTree -Path "./z" -Debug -ForceDebug #Remove file. -Debug Prints debug messages and -ForceDebug forces to prints messages if DebugPreference is SilentlyContinue.

Get-ChildItem -Force
```

---

**Output**

```
███ Test 1
"Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\Z-Config.json"

███ Test 2

███ Test 3
[
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\Z-CoreFxs.ps1",
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\Z-Config.json",
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\z",
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\y",
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\X-Update-PowerShellCoreFxs.ps1",       
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\x",
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\HappyBirthday Unicorn\\UnicornMLP.pdf",
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\HappyBirthday Unicorn\\Unicorn5.pdf",  
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\HappyBirthday Unicorn\\Unicorn4.pdf",  
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\HappyBirthday Unicorn\\Unicorn3.pdf",  
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\HappyBirthday Unicorn\\Unicorn2.pdf",  
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\HappyBirthday Unicorn\\Unicorn.png",   
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\HappyBirthday Unicorn\\Unicorn.pdf",   
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\HappyBirthday Unicorn\\Unicorn-free-printable-cake-toppers.png",
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\HappyBirthday Unicorn\\Unicorn - Original.pdf",
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\HappyBirthday Unicorn\\hontana.zip",
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\HappyBirthday Unicorn\\hand-drawn-unicorn-birthday-invitation-template (2).zip",
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\HappyBirthday Unicorn\\hand-drawing-rainbow-design.zip",
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\HappyBirthday Unicorn\\collection-of-unicorns-and-hearts-with-rainbows.zip",
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\HappyBirthday Unicorn",
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx"
]

███ Test 4
[
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\Z-CoreFxs.ps1",
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\Z-Config.json",
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\z",
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\y",
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\X-Update-PowerShellCoreFxs.ps1",
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\x",
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\HappyBirthday Unicorn\\UnicornMLP.pdf",
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\HappyBirthday Unicorn\\Unicorn5.pdf",
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\HappyBirthday Unicorn\\Unicorn4.pdf",
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\HappyBirthday Unicorn\\Unicorn3.pdf",
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\HappyBirthday Unicorn\\Unicorn2.pdf",
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\HappyBirthday Unicorn\\Unicorn.png",
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\HappyBirthday Unicorn\\Unicorn.pdf",
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\HappyBirthday Unicorn\\Unicorn-free-printable-cake-toppers.png",
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\HappyBirthday Unicorn\\Unicorn - Original.pdf",
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\HappyBirthday Unicorn\\hontana.zip",
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\HappyBirthday Unicorn\\hand-drawn-unicorn-birthday-invitation-template (2).zip",
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\HappyBirthday Unicorn\\hand-drawing-rainbow-design.zip",
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\HappyBirthday Unicorn\\collection-of-unicorns-and-hearts-with-rainbows.zip",
  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem::C:\\Users\\Megam\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\pwshcfx\\HappyBirthday Unicorn"
]

DEBUG: Deleted: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\Megam\OneDrive\Escritorio\pwshcfx\HappyBirthday Unicorn\UnicornMLP.pdf
DEBUG: Deleted: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\Megam\OneDrive\Escritorio\pwshcfx\HappyBirthday Unicorn\Unicorn5.pdf
DEBUG: Deleted: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\Megam\OneDrive\Escritorio\pwshcfx\HappyBirthday Unicorn\Unicorn4.pdf
DEBUG: Deleted: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\Megam\OneDrive\Escritorio\pwshcfx\HappyBirthday Unicorn\Unicorn3.pdf
DEBUG: Deleted: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\Megam\OneDrive\Escritorio\pwshcfx\HappyBirthday Unicorn\Unicorn2.pdf
DEBUG: Deleted: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\Megam\OneDrive\Escritorio\pwshcfx\HappyBirthday Unicorn\Unicorn.png
DEBUG: Deleted: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\Megam\OneDrive\Escritorio\pwshcfx\HappyBirthday Unicorn\Unicorn.pdf
DEBUG: Deleted: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\Megam\OneDrive\Escritorio\pwshcfx\HappyBirthday Unicorn\Unicorn-free-printable-cake-toppers.png
DEBUG: Deleted: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\Megam\OneDrive\Escritorio\pwshcfx\HappyBirthday Unicorn\Unicorn - Original.pdf
DEBUG: Deleted: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\Megam\OneDrive\Escritorio\pwshcfx\HappyBirthday Unicorn\hontana.zip
DEBUG: Deleted: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\Megam\OneDrive\Escritorio\pwshcfx\HappyBirthday Unicorn\hand-drawn-unicorn-birthday-invitation-template (2).zip
DEBUG: Deleted: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\Megam\OneDrive\Escritorio\pwshcfx\HappyBirthday Unicorn\hand-drawing-rainbow-design.zip
DEBUG: Deleted: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\Megam\OneDrive\Escritorio\pwshcfx\HappyBirthday Unicorn\collection-of-unicorns-and-hearts-with-rainbows.zip
DEBUG: Deleted: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\Megam\OneDrive\Escritorio\pwshcfx\HappyBirthday Unicorn
DEBUG: Deleted: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\Megam\OneDrive\Escritorio\pwshcfx\x
DEBUG: Deleted: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\Megam\OneDrive\Escritorio\pwshcfx\y
DEBUG: Deleted: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\Megam\OneDrive\Escritorio\pwshcfx\z


    Directory: C:\Users\Megam\OneDrive\Escritorio\pwshcfx

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
la---           17/5/2021     1:57            272 X-Update-PowerShellCoreFxs.ps1
la---           14/5/2021    18:51            252 Z-Config.json
la---           17/5/2021     4:04          30931 Z-CoreFxs.ps1
```

**tree . /f**

```
C:\USERS\MEGAM\ONEDRIVE\ESCRITORIO\PWSHCFX
    X-Update-PowerShellCoreFxs.ps1
    Z-Config.json
    Z-CoreFxs.ps1

No subfolders exist
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below powershell script. This script will skip to the next file/folder if got stuck with some error like "Remove-Item : The tag present in the reparse point buffer is invalid."

```
# Get a list of all the folders to be deleted
$foldersToDelete = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path "C:\Path\To\Folders"

# Delete each folder recursively, skipping to the next file if stuck with an error
foreach ($folder in $foldersToDelete) {
    try {
        Remove-Item -Path $folder.FullName -Recurse -Force
    } catch {
        Write-Host "Failed to delete folder '$folder.FullName': $_"
        continue
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

```
$users = get-childitem \\ServerName\c$\users\ | select -ExpandProperty name

foreach ($user in $users)

{
remove-item -path "\\Servername\c$\Users\$user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office365\PowerShell\*" -Force -Recurse
Write-Warning "$user Cleaned"
}
```

Wrote the above to clean some logfiles without deleting the parent directory and this works perfectly!

Answer (score -3):

```
rm -r <folder_name>
c:\>rm -r "my photos"
```

Comment: Please explain that further such that others can learn from your answer

Comment: This won't work, as it tries to delete directories before they are empty.