# Delete folder if folders and archives on it not have changes in 100 days

Tags: powershell

I need a powershell script to do:

read folders:

folder1
folder2
folder3

and delete only folders "folderX and subfolders" if  in this folderX (and subfolders, and all archives on it) not have changes in 100 days

I need to save a log

Could you help me? :)

Best Regards!!!

Comment: You asked almost the same question yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44262642/delete-folder-and-subfolder-if-is-not-used-powershell

Comment: Possible duplicate of [delete folder and subfolder if is not used (Powershell)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44262642/delete-folder-and-subfolder-if-is-not-used-powershell)