# Why is the system looking for 'react-is` inside `prop-types`?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-proptypes

For some reason, the system's looking for something called `react-is`, leading to this error:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/prop-types/node_modules/react-is/index.js
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\mikwee\linkroots\node_modules\prop-types\node_modules\react-is\index.js'
```

It is a package, but it's looking for it inside `prop-types` for some reason. This error started when I imported a React Bootstrap component. I'm not sure what other info to add here, so if you need to know more, let me know please!

Comment: try an `npm i` to install all dependencies

Comment: 1. I'm actually on Yarn, so I just used `yarn`. 2. It says everything's already up-to-date.

Comment: react-is is a dependency of prop-types, which is a dependency of react-bootstrap (and many others). When you `rm -rf node_modules/` and then `yarn`, do you still have the issue?

Comment: How do you do that on PowerShell?

Comment: PowerShell `rm -r -fo node_modules` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1752751/6151924))

Comment: OK, so I did `rm -r -fo node_modules/`, because that's what an answer on this site told me to do. Got tons of errors saying it can't delete directory X because it's not empty. Then did `yarn`, and still got the error.

Comment: You have to delete that directory-- however that's done in your terminal. The `yarn` command in the answer you found is premised on deleting that directory.

Comment: I don't know how, but the problem just got fixed by itself. I guess there's no need for that!

Answer (score 2):

Just delete the node_modules folder in your explorer and run `yarn` again.

If it still fails you can install react-is explicitly using

`yarn add react-is`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

try an `npm i react-is@latest` only for yarn

Comment: So like `yarn upgrade react-is`? Doesn't work for me