# How to quietly remove a directory with content in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, directory

Using PowerShell, is it possible to remove some directory that contains files without prompting to confirm action?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recursively delete an entire directory with PowerShell 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752677/how-to-recursively-delete-an-entire-directory-with-powershell-2-0)

Answer (score 566, accepted):

```
Remove-Item -LiteralPath "foldertodelete" -Force -Recurse
```

or, with shorter version

```
rm /path -r -force
```

Comment: I've found that I need to run this twice when run on a directory that contains subdirectories. The first time, there will be a lot of "The directory is not empty" errors.  The second time, it completes with no errors.

Comment: If I want delete only contents of folder but not delete folder?

Comment: @Kiquenet- This works for me, if I add a trailing slash to the path, so this example becomes Remove-Item .\foldertodelete\* -Force -Recurse

Comment: If you want it to ignore a missing folder you can add `-ErrorAction Ignore`, although that will also hide other errors.

Comment: @Kiquenet Then you can use wildcards to remove everything within that folder: `Remove-Item './folder/*'`. If you really want to clear out only files of all folders you can list all leafs and pipe it to the Remove-Item cmdlet `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | Remove-Item`

Comment: To make the commands shorter 
```rm /path -r -force```

Comment: rm /path -r -force doesn't work at all, it just spits out a ton of error messages about directories not being empty.

Comment: this doesn't work

Comment: so close, i tried `rm -rf`, which didn't work, so the closest to linux is `rm -r -fo`

Answer (score 88):

From [PowerShell remove force answer](https://serverfault.com/a/199994/107224): 
help Remove-Item says:

> The Recurse parameter in this cmdlet does not work properly

The command to workaround is

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Destination -Recurse | Remove-Item -force -recurse
```

And then delete the folder itself

```
Remove-Item $Destination -Force
```

Comment: If I want delete only contents of folder but not delete folder?

Comment: @beppe9000: I believe, yes. In the recent scripts I am using `Remove-Item -Recurse -Force $dir` and it works.

Comment: Ok, but I just read that the problem is still here on the windows 10 extended `Get-Help Remove-Item` documentation obtained after `Update-Help` is run...

Comment: Get-ChildItem should also have the -Force argument, so that it also returns  hidden files/folders.

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim - I've used this and it has decreased intermittent failures, but they still occasionally happen. If Remove-Item -recurse is problematic for the top-level directory, can you explain why it would not be similarly problematic when it is piped into with the workaround line? Get-ChildItem -recurse doesn't return the children in a bottom-up order. Does Remove-Item order its pipelined input?

Comment: I think a potential failure mode with this is if $Destination is not specified, say while running a script that composes that value, the command deletes all the files in the directory in which you are working, which happened to me, but thanks be to git...

Comment: I have modularized this answer into a function -- see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37438430)

Comment: Great if you want a shorter option : `rm <path> -r -fo`

Comment: Note that PowerShell no longer includes the scary comment, "The Recurse parameter in this cmdlet does not work properly."  Instead, they just point out that Recurse and Include aren't compatible.

Answer (score 67):

This worked for me:

```
Remove-Item $folderPath -Force  -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Thus the folder is removed with all files in there and it is not producing error if folder path doesn't exists.

Comment: This does not delete the folder.

Comment: @variable, it deleted the folder when I tried.

Answer (score 47):

**2018 Update**

In the current version of PowerShell (tested with v5.1 on Windows 10 and Windows 11 in 2023) one can use the simpler Unix syntax `rm -R .\DirName` to silently delete the directory `.\DirName` with all subdirectories and files it may contain. In fact many common Unix commands work in the same way in PowerShell as in a Linux command line.

One can also clean up a folder, but not the folder itself, using `rm -R .\DirName\*` (noted by Jeff in the comments).

Comment: none of the powershell commands nor this one works for me on a 2016 server core computer.  They all say, `cannot be removed because it is not empty'. I also tried the rd command in windows.  I can move the folder anywhere, just can't delete.

Answer (score 26):

in short, We can use `rm -r -fo {folderName}` to remove the folder recursively (remove all the files and folders inside) and force

Comment: Thanks for using -r and -fo. That way the command is much concise.

Comment: still i wonder why powershell not just inherit the whole commands from linux, say rm -rf folder/

Answer (score 13):

To delete content without a folder you can use the following:

```
Remove-Item "foldertodelete\*" -Force -Recurse
```

Answer (score 10):

`rm -Force -Recurse -Confirm:$false $directory2Delete` didn't work in the [PowerShell ISE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315244.aspx), but it worked through the regular PowerShell CLI.

I hope this helps. It was driving me bannanas.

Comment: Thank you, same goes for me! FInally this folder was deleted when calling from `PowerShell CLI` and not while developing in `PowerShell ISE`.

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me:

```
Remove-Item C:\folder_name -Force -Recurse
```

Answer (score 6):

Powershell works with relative folders. The `Remove-Item` has couple of useful aliases which aligns with unix. Some examples:

```
rm -R -Force ./directory
del -R -Force ./directory/*
```

Answer (score 4):

Below is a copy-pasteable implementation of Michael Freidgeim's answer

```
function Delete-FolderAndContents {
    # http://stackoverflow.com/a/9012108

    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)] [string] $folder_path
    )

    process {
        $child_items = ([array] (Get-ChildItem -Path $folder_path -Recurse -Force))
        if ($child_items) {
            $null = $child_items | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
        }
        $null = Remove-Item $folder_path -Force
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$LogPath = "E:\" # Your local of directories
$Folders = Get-Childitem $LogPath -dir -r | Where-Object {$_.name -like "*temp*"}
foreach ($Folder in $Folders) 
{
    $Item =  $Folder.FullName
    Write-Output $Item
    Remove-Item $Item -Force -Recurse
}
```

Comment: On script above i print fullname of folder and remove it. \o/

Answer (score 2):

Since my directory was in C:\users I had to run my powershell as administrator,

```
del ./[your Folder name] -Force -Recurse
```

this command worked for me.

Comment: Just as a side-note: `del` is an alias for `Remove-Item`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$LogPath = "E:\" # Your local of directories
$Folders = Get-Childitem $LogPath -dir -r | Where-Object {$_.name -like "*grav*"} # Your keyword name directories

foreach ($Folder in $Folders) 
{
    $Item =  $Folder.FullName
    Write-Output $Item
    Remove-Item $Item -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

Comment: On script above i print fullname of folder and remove it. A good job...

Comment: Hi Anderson, you should edit answers if you are not planning to add 2 different answers, maybe you want to delete one of them?

Answer (score 1):

If you have your folder as an object, let's say that you created it in the same script using next command:

```
$folder = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "c:\tmp" -Name "myFolder"
```

Then you can just remove it like this in the same script

```
$folder.Delete($true)
```

$true - states for recursive removal

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **concatenate** a *variable* with a fixed path and a *string* as the dynamic path into a whole *path* to **remove** the folder, you may need the following command:

```
$fixPath = "C:\Users\myUserName\Desktop"
Remove-Item ("$fixPath" + "\Folder\SubFolder") -Recurse
```

In the variable `$newPath` the concatenate path is now: `"C:\Users\myUserName\Desktop\Folder\SubFolder"`

So you can remove several directories from the starting point (`"C:\Users\myUserName\Desktop"`), which is already defined and fixed in the variable `$fixPath`.

```
$fixPath = "C:\Users\myUserName\Desktop"
Remove-Item ("$fixPath" + "\Folder\SubFolder") -Recurse
Remove-Item ("$fixPath" + "\Folder\SubFolder1") -Recurse
Remove-Item ("$fixPath" + "\Folder\SubFolder2") -Recurse
```

Comment: I guess you mean `Remove-Item` and not `Remote-Item`.

Answer (score 1):

Some multi-level directory folders need to be deleted twice, which has troubled me for a long time. Here is my final code, it works for me, and cleans up nicely, hope it helps.

```
function ForceDelete {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [string] $path
    )
    
    rm -r -fo $path
    
    if (Test-Path -Path $path){
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
        Write-Host "Force delete retrying..." -ForegroundColor white -BackgroundColor red
        rm -r -fo $path
    }
}

ForceDelete('.\your-folder-name')
ForceDelete('.\your-file-name.php')
```

Comment: this is just a wrapper around answers already posted. what benefit do you see in your Answer over the others? ///// also, calling a function with `()` around the values is not correct in PoSh ... that just says "treat this as an array".

Answer (score -1):

It looks cumbersome, but I use this to have everything reliably deleted, even if there are very long pathname\filenames (exceeding 259 characters):

```
  &mkdir    empty_dummy_directory              >$Null
  &robocopy empty_dummy_directory $folder /mir >$Null
  &rmdir    empty_dummy_directory
  &rmdir    $folder
```

Source of the solution and some more details and discussions are [here](https://superuser.com/a/467814).